# Binding FontFamily ViewModel's Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to bind the FontFamily of a TextBox to a property I created on my ViewModel

Here's my XAML :

```
<TextBox Text="Test Font Binding" FontFamily="{Binding FontFirstContent}" />
```

And here the property in my ViewModel :

```
public FontFamily FontFirstContent
{
    get { return new FontFamily("Verdana"); }
}
```

When the view is loaded, the getter of the property is correctly firing but it's not passed on the view.
All bindings on my view are working except this one, so i don't understand what's wrong with it ?

Edit :
Okay it works fine ! I was just working on the wrong FontFamily object..
I've used :

```
System.Drawing.FontFamily
```

But the FontFamily must be of type :

```
System.Windows.Media.FontFamily
```

Comment: Thats strange, I setup a quick project. It works for me. Do you properly have the DataContext set?

Comment: Can you paste the code from your viewmodel, xaml and view code behind (if there is any)?

Comment: It seems it's working for me too if I don't use a ViewModel.. So if I place my Property in my view's code behind and define : DataContext = this; it's working. But if I do : DataContext = new MyViewModel(); it doesn't work. Very strange..

Comment: What I did was DataContext = new MyViewModel(); in the views code behind and that worked.

Comment: What actual value does `FontFamily` have in the view, according to e.g. Snoop?

Comment: Ohhh.. Okay problem is solved ! I was working with :
System.Drawing.FontFamily in place of System.Windows.Media.FontFamily
I'm really sorry thanks for your replies !

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I added to a `ResourceDictionary`intended to be a default style for my application:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="MyFontFamily">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
```

When you want to use it, you set the `FontFamily` property like this:

```
<Label Content="Something" FontFamily="{DynamicResource MyFontFamily}"/>
```

Don't forget to put it in a `ResourceDictionary` or any Control Resource.

Hope it helps;

Comment: I know styles in a ResourceDictionary but in my case I must change the FontFamily dynamically when user do some action. The code I paste wasn't the code I'm really using. I do some others tests on my getter. That's why I place a property in my ViewModel. Thanks

Comment: You can change it Dynamically using the `FindResource` method. That's exactly what I do. I have 4 FontFamily that I change "Dynamically"